# How to use mockito 3.0 with JUnit 5?

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

How to "extend" `JUnit 5` with `mockito 3`?

In `JUnit 5` to use `mockito` priory to version `3.0` a test class needs to be annotated with a new `JUnit 5` annotation `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`, e.g.:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class TestClass {
   @Mock
   DependencyA dependancyA;

   public void myTest() {
   ...
   }
}
```

and as such there is no need to use any more `MockitoRule` with `@Rule` annotation.

I have tried today  beta release `mockito-android 3.0.0-beta1` and it does not have `MockitoExtension` class.

What should I use instead? I couldn't find any documentation for version 3.0, which is understandable as it is still in beta.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `MockitoExtension` is published in the `mockito-junit-jupiter` artifact.

You can add a dependency on it as follows.

**Maven**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
  <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
  <version>2.27.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Gradle**

```
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:2.27.0'
```

**Further Resources**

- https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1517#issuecomment-429621891
- https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-junit-jupiter/2.27.0/jar